# Add multiple items to Paypal in single form using hosted_button_id

Tags: paypal

I want to setup a single form on a site to purchase multiple products via PayPal. The products are set in the PayPal account and each has a hosted_button_id.

The form would contain a series of descriptions and quantity fields, all initially set to zero. The customer could then add desired quantities against each product and submit the form with a *single* 'Buy now' button.

Is this possible with PayPal? I don't particularly want a 'cart' experience and I don't want to pass product prices (instead using the data stored at PayPal).

thanks

Answer (score 4):

In the end I concluded you can't do this.

I tried everything, including AJAXing the submission and send the submission via a hidden iFrame to keep the user on my site. Nothing worked. It seems PayPal are very keen to enforce their approved shopping workflow when using their cart.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but you'll need to do some server-side programming.  You build an "encrypted button" programmatically, and submit that to PayPal.

My store page at https://secure.entrian.com/store/store.html does it - it prompts for some information, sends that to the server to be turned into an encrypted button, and then submits that to PayPal.

The JavaScript looks like this, where `$license_name` and `$quantity` are the fields that I'm prompting for, and `formgen.py` is a server-side Python script that builds and signs the request using OpenSSL according to PayPal's documentation:

```
$paypal_form.submit(function () {
   var response = $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: 'formgen.py?' + serialize({
           licenseName: $license_name.val(),
           quantity: $quantity.val()
       }),
       async: false
   }).responseText;

   if (response.indexOf('PKCS7') >= 0) {
       $encrypted.val(response);
   } else {
       $payment_errors.text(response).show(easing_duration);
       return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

The form looks like this (simplified rather):

```
<form id="paypal-form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="encrypted" name="encrypted" value="">
<button id="buynow" class="submit-button btn" type="submit">Buy Now</button>
</form>
```

That `<input name="encrypted" ...>` gets populated with the AJAX response before the form gets submitted to PayPal.